# Installing eggs in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

In MSYS2, I tried to intall a Chicken egg with::

```
chicken-install http-client
```

I get several errors like the following:

```
"c:\msys64\usr\local\bin\csc" -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode    mathh.scm -shared -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -output-file mathh.so -emit-import-library mathh -emit-type-file mathh.types -local -no-procedure-checks
mathh.c:24:1: error: static declaration of 'log2' follows non-static declaration
 log2( double x )
 ^~~~
In file included from c:/msys64/usr/local/include/chicken/chicken.h:131:0,
                 from mathh.c:11:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/math.h:773:25: note: previous declaration of 'log2' was here
   extern double __cdecl log2 (double);
                         ^~~~
mathh.c:41:1: error: static declaration of 'log1p' follows non-static declaration
 log1p( double x )
^~~~~
```

## Edit

The dependency:

```
chicken-install mathh
```

gives:

```
...
mathh.c: In function 'stub181':
mathh.c:357:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mm_hypot'; did you mean '_hypot'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 C_r=C_flonum(&C_a,mm_hypot(t0,t1));
                   ^~~~~~~~
                   _hypot
mathh.o:mathh.c:(.text+0x177f): undefined reference to `mm_hypot'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 1: ""gcc" "mathh.o" -o "mathh.so" -Wl,--enable-auto-import -shared -Lc:\msys64\usr\local\lib\ -lchicken -lm -lws2_32"

Error: shell command failed with nonzero exit status 1:

  ""c:\msys64\usr\local\bin\csc" -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode    mathh.scm -shared -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -output-file mathh.so -emit-import-library mathh -emit-type-file mathh.types -local -no-procedure-checks"


Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
70
"\"\"c:\\msys64\\usr\\local\\bin\\csi\" -bnq -setup-mode -e \"(require-lib...
```

## Edit

Fix proposed by @krl:

```
msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64 # see http://wiki.call-cc.org/msys2
export CHICKEN_PREFIX="c:\msys64\usr\local\\"
export CHICKEN_REPOSITORY="c:\msys64\usr\local\lib\chicken\8\\"
chicken-install -retrieve mathh
sed  -i.bak -r 's/define +mathh-compile-options.+\(/&\n  -C -mwin32/' ./mathh/mathh.setup
chicken-install test
chicken-install -test -transport local -location . mathh
```

That still gives the following errors:

```
...

installing mathh: ...
changing current directory to C:\msys64\home\user\.\mathh
  ""c:\msys64\usr\local\bin\csi" -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"mathh\" \"\"))" "mathh.setup""
  "c:\msys64\usr\local\bin\csc" -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode mathh.scm -shared -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -output-file mathh.so -emit-import-library mathh -emit-type-file mathh.types -local -no-procedure-checks
mathh.c:29:1: error: static declaration of 'log2' follows non-static declaration
 log2( double x )
 ^~~~
In file included from c:/msys64/usr/local/include/chicken/chicken.h:131:0,
                 from mathh.c:11:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/math.h:773:25: note: previous                                   declaration of 'log2' was here
   extern double __cdecl log2 (double);
                         ^~~~
... further errors like above
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in the mathh egg. I've asked its author to take a look and he's published a new version. Can you try again?

Comment: I run `chicken-install mathh`. Still no luck. See question edit.

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.davidegrayson.com/windev/msys2/ it appears the MSYS2 -mwin32 gcc option is needed to define _WIN32. mathh uses defined(_WIN32) to trigger expansion of the q&d implementations of log2, etc. for windows.

the mathh egg mathh.setup file can be modified to supply compile-options. see the definition of mathh-compile-options in mathh.setup.

```
ex: (define mathh-compile-options '(-local -no-procedure-checks -mwin32))
```

Comment: sorry : (define mathh-compile-options '(-local -no-procedure-checks -C -mwin32))

Comment: As I understand, this assumes that I should make a separate download of the `mathh` egg,  modify `mathh.setup` and recompile.  Any pointer on how to do this?

Comment: cd <some workdir>
chicken-install -retrieve mathh
... edit ./mathh/mathh.setup ...
chicken-install -test -transport local -location . mathh

Comment: Still get build errors. Please, check my last question edit.

Comment: why isn't _WIN32 defined? try explicit def : (define mathh-compile-options `(-local -no-procedure-checks -C -D_WIN32)

Comment: seems log2, log1p, ... are now available. remove the offending C procedures from the source (where the compiler complains of a math.h extern).

Comment: Yes! In fact, in `mathh.scm`, after `#elif defined(__CYGWIN__) || ...`, I added the 3 lines:
`#if defined(_WIN32) `, `#pragma message "_WIN32" `, `#endif `. I always get the  #pragma message: with `-C -mwin32`, and also with no compiler options. So the code conditional to `_WIN32` is executed, and the related maths functions are defined. But they have been already defined in `C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/math.h`. Hence the error: "static declaration of 'log2' follows non-static declaration".

Comment: Note also that I am using `msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64` as from [wiki.call-cc.org/msys2](http://wiki.call-cc.org/msys2) and not the subsystem `msys` of MSYS2.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released [http-client](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/http-client) version 0.16 where I ripped out the overly complex [md5](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/md5) dependency, and replaced it with the new [simple-md5](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/simple-md5) egg.

This should be much easier to install. It should appear on the egg mirrors shortly.